# Testing Angular 2 service that returns a Promise

Tags: angular, testing, asynchronous

I'm trying to unit test a service which should use fake http backend, provided by Angular's in-memory data service. This is the relevant code:

```
describe('getCars() method ', ()  => {
      it('should return a resolved Promise', inject([DataService], (service: DataService) => {
        service.getCars().then((value) => {
          expect(value.length).toBe(3);
       });
    }));
  });
```

The problem is I can't use Jasmine's *done* callback to treat the asynchronous **service.getCars()** call, because of how inject function works. I can't use *async* test helper neither, because it can't work with promises. So I have no idea how to wait for promise to resolve---the test just runs without ever reaching *expect*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `async`, which will wrap it a zone, waiting for all asynchronous tasks to complete before the test completes.

```
import { async } from '@angular/core/testing';

                                   // !!!!!!!
it('should return a resolved Promise', async(inject([DataService], (service: DataService)=>{
  service.getCars().then((value) => {
    expect(value.length).toBe(3);
  });
})));
```

Also another option is to not use `inject` at all. You can just get services from the `TestBed`. It's a lot clearer

```
let service: DataService;

beforeEach(() => {
  const injector = TestBed.configureTestingModule({});
  service = injector.get(DataService);
});
```

No need for `inject`, and it's a lot less verbose. You can now use `done`. Or if you want, still do it the Angular way, and use `async`.

**See also:**

- [Docs testing section on async](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/testing.html#!#async)

Comment: The way with getting the service from a TestBed works, thanks. However when I try the async solution, Karma test runner prints out an error: "Cannot use setInterval from within an async zone test"

Comment: Yeah, either you are explicitly using setInterval, or something like Observable.delay is using it. It can't be used in `async`. You might be able to use it with `fakeAsync` though. See the link in the "see also". It shows how to use `fakeAsync`